# How to use f:setPropertyActionListener with p:splitButton?

Tags: primefaces

I have this working button in a p:dataTable

```
<p:commandButton update=":dialog" oncomplete="PF('dialog').show()" title="Do something">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{transaction}" target="#{transactionModel.selectedTx}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

It sets the selectedTx in the model so that I can do stuff with it in the dialog.

Now I want to add a new functionality to my button, so I chose a `p:splitButton`:

```
<p:splitButton update=":dialog" oncomplete="PF('dialog').show()" title="Do something">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{transaction}" target="#{transactionModel.selectedTx}" />
    <p:menuitem value="Do something else" oncomplete="PF('otherDialog').show()" update=":otherDialog" />
</p:splitButton>
```

When I use the new button, **the selectedTx is not set**. Only the first button works.

**How to update my property in the model when the new button is clicked ?**

Comment: not sure if this is valid at all, but did you try the `setPropertyActionListener` inside the `p:menuitem` tag?

Comment: I tried and it did not work, but I had a missing "update" - now it works. However, the selectedTx is not always updated, but I am having  a hard time finding out why. So far I cannot consistently reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add the setPropertyActionListener inside of the menuitem (as Apostolos suggested), and the datatable needed to be updated (instead of only the dialog):

```
<p:splitButton update="datatable :dialog" oncomplete="PF('dialog').show()" title="Do something">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{transaction}" target="#{transactionModel.selectedTx}" />

    <p:menuitem value="Do something else" oncomplete="PF('otherDialog').show()" update="datatable :otherDialog">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{transaction}" target="#{transactionModel.selectedTx}" />
    </p:menuitem>
</p:splitButton>
```